# assign an image and a Background color according to the web Service values for each ListviewItem

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

based on this Post [post link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35294648/select-each-listviewitem-and-apply-a-modification-in-a-universal-app),I am having problem in modifying the Background of a Button and the images according to the values that I have get from a Web Service:

this is what I did:MainPage.cs:

```
ObservableCollection<Item> Locals = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
public async void getListePerSearch()
    {
        try
        {
            UriString2 = "URL";
            var http = new HttpClient();
            http.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
            var response = await http.GetStringAsync(UriString2);
            var rootObject1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NvBarberry.Models.RootObject>(response);

           foreach (var item in rootObject1.locals)
                {
                    Item listItem = new Item();
                    if (item.fav == 1)
                        {
                         listItem.ButtonColor= new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow); //Yellow
                        }

                        else
                        {
                        listItem.ButtonColor= new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);//Gray
                        }

                        if (item.aime == 1)
                        {
                        listItem.MyUrl2 = new Uri("ms-appx:///images/coueur_rouge.png", UriKind.Absolute);
                        }

                        else
                        {
                        listItem.MyUrl2 = new Uri("ms-appx:///images/like.png", UriKind.Absolute);
                        }

                        if (item.aimepas == 1)
                        {
                        listItem.MyUrl1 = new Uri("ms-appx:///images/icon_cer_selected.png", UriKind.Absolute);
                        }

                        else
                        {
                        listItem.MyUrl1 = new Uri("ms-appx:///images/icon_cer.png", UriKind.Absolute);
                        }
                        Locals.Add(listItem);
                }


                listme.ItemsSource = Locals;//I get 4 Items here
   }
```

and this is Item.cs:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private Uri myUrl1;
    public Uri MyUrl1
    {
        get { return myUrl1; }
        set
        {
            myUrl1 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MyUrl1");
        }
    }


    private Uri myUrl2;
    public Uri MyUrl2
    {
        get { return myUrl2; }
        set
        {
            myUrl2 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MyUrl2");
        }
    }

    private SolidColorBrush buttonColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
    public SolidColorBrush ButtonColor
    {
        get { return buttonColor; }
        set
        {
            buttonColor = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ButtonColor");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Locals.cs:

```
public class Locals
{
    public int fav { get; set; }
    public int aime { get; set; }
    public int aimepas { get; set; }

}
```

and finally this is the xaml :

```
 <ListView  x:Name="listme">
 <ListView.ItemTemplate >
   <DataTemplate >
     <Grid>
       ...
      <Button Background="{Binding ButtonColor} Tapped="Button_Tapped"/>
      <Image Source="{Binding MyUrl2}"/>
      <Image Source="{Binding MyUrl1}"/>
     </Grid>
   </DataTemplate >
 </ListView.ItemTemplate >
</ListView >
```

I get as a result 4 items in the ListView not 2 as you can see in the json data,the modification does not apply on each ListViewItem
did I make a mistake in my code??How can I correct my code to get only the 2 Items and assign an image and a Background Color according to the web Service values for each ListviewItem
this is the result of Debugging:
[image]
thanks for help

Update:rootObject1.locals:
[image]

Comment: How many times does the getListePerSearch get called? How many items are there in the rootObject1.locals?

Comment: getListePerSearch is called one Time Sir when page is loaded,and for rootObject1.locals I have updated my Post

Comment: it contains the correct values